# Trying to use my first DB connection in Java - I'm getting loads of errors and I don't know why

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

So I have to do a small app in Java - I have no background in it so I don't really know many things (syntactically) about it. I'm using the internet and intellij for generating some code. (like the models)

The program builds successfully, but then I get these runtime errors:

```
Error at initialing DatabaseManager: Exception [EclipseLink-7107] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.7.v20200504-69f2c2b80d): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Error encountered during string decryption.
Internal Exception: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: BEAD66C6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javax.persistence.EntityManager.getTransaction()" because "this.entityManager" is null
    at database.DatabaseConnection.executeTransaction(DatabaseConnection.java:23)
    at database.daos.EchipaDao.create(EchipaDao.java:23)
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Here's my code:

DatabaseConnection.Java

```
package database;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public DatabaseConnection() {
        this.initTransaction();
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public boolean executeTransaction(Consumer<EntityManager> action) {
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            entityTransaction.begin();
            action.accept(entityManager);
            entityTransaction.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.err.println("Transaction error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            entityTransaction.rollback();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean initTransaction() {
        try {
            entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ProiectMipPersistence");
            entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error at initialing DatabaseManager: " + e.getMessage().toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

IDao.java

```
package database.daos;

import java.util.List;

public interface IDao<T> {
    T get(Long id);
    List<T> getAll ();
    void create (T t);
}
```

EchipaDao.java

```
package database.daos;

import database.DatabaseConnection;
import database.models.EchipaEntity;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public class EchipaDao implements IDao<EchipaEntity>{
    DatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection();

    public EchipaEntity get(Long id) {
        return connection.getEntityManager().find(EchipaEntity.class, Long.valueOf(id));
    }

    @Override
    public List<EchipaEntity> getAll() {
        TypedQuery<EchipaEntity> query = connection.getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT a FROM EchipaEntity a", EchipaEntity.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public void create(EchipaEntity echipa) {
        connection.executeTransaction(entityManager -> entityManager.persist(echipa));
    }
}
```

EchipaEntity.java

```
package database.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "echipa", schema = "public", catalog = "dbfdlur9ijidho")
public class EchipaEntity {
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "nume_echipa", nullable = false, length = -1)
    private String numeEchipa;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    public String getNumeEchipa() {
        return numeEchipa;
    }

    public void setNumeEchipa(String numeEchipa) {
        this.numeEchipa = numeEchipa;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        EchipaEntity that = (EchipaEntity) o;
        return id == that.id && Objects.equals(numeEchipa, that.numeEchipa);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(numeEchipa, id);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import database.daos.EchipaDao;
import database.models.EchipaEntity;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EchipaDao echipaDao = new EchipaDao();
        EchipaEntity echipaEntity = new EchipaEntity();

        echipaEntity.setNumeEchipa("test");

        echipaDao.create(echipaEntity);

        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I tried searching online (honestly, just for the first one, because I feel like if I get rid of that the rest will disappear too) - I couldn't find anything meaningful to my case.

So, why are those errors happening and how can I fix them?

//Edit:

Added pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    <!-- ECLIPSELINK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- POSTGRES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: I presume you are using maven no manage dependencies. Can you share your `pom.xml` please?

Comment: See [Introduction to JDBC](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc)

Comment: I don’t use Jakarta Persistence, but… Your error message says `this.entityManager` is null. So perhaps you should be debugging your line `entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();`.

Comment: @gmanjon I did now :)

Comment: @BasilBourque okay. I will look into it a bit later. Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I misses that `initTransactiom`. Can you please upload your `persistemce.xml` and where is it placed? Thanks.

Comment: To better trace the error use `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.err.println`, this way you will have the full information about the error and where does it come from. Otherwise you will lose all the `Caused by` deep inside the stack trace.

Comment: @gmanjon persistence.xml - https://pastebin.com/U0kJD6Mm. It is placed in src->main->resources->META-INF/persistence.xml.

Comment: e.printStackTrace() result - https://pastebin.com/JkTCm2gh

Comment: I updated and undeleted my previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the stacktrace you can see the root of the problem:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 2666A3B3
```

Although a bit cryptic, this usally means an incompatibility of libraries.

Looking closer at your dependencies, you are using a fairly new version of eclipselink (2.7.7 from year 2020), and quite old versions of the other dependencies (javax.persistence 2.0.0 from 2010, and postgres 9.3 from 2014).

If you go to the eclipselink 2.7.7 maven page (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.7.7) you can see that the dependency used to compile it was jakarta.persistence (the new denomination for javax.persistence) 2.2.3, from 2019, which would make a lot more sense.

In the case of Postgress driver, you can see in its documentation (https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html) :

> Current Version 42.3.1
>
> This is the current version of the driver. Unless you have unusual requirements (running old applications or JVMs), this is the driver you should be using. It supports PostgreSQL 8.2 or newer and requires Java 8 or newer. It contains support for SSL and the javax.sql package.

So, to tidy up your dependencies do the following changes in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- POSTGRES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also, you are defining the maven compiler plugin to use java version 16, but in the properties `maven.compiler.xxx` point to java 17. Those are exactly the same, so either you specify the properties ornthe plugin configuration. If you are not using additional plugin configuration I would always go for the properties. <s>And make it 16 or 17 depending on your jdk version (I would use 17, as it is the last LTS jdk version)</s>

Following this eclipselink github project thread (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/269) jdk 11 support was supposedly added in 3.0.0.

**Update** after local testing

That means that, theoretically, using 2.7.7 you are tied to use jdk 8. But I have just run your code samples correctly with jdk 11. (16 and 17 failed with the `Unsupported class file major version 60` and `61`.

Even only changing the JDK to 11 in your original question wouldn't have been enough, you would have gotten `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported` because of incompatibility issues between libraries as mentioned at the beginning of the answer.

**Update** after updating dependencies

Ok. This is wierd, but I think we got to the final problem. Apart from all the libraries compatibility, JDK versions support, which is real, if we analyze deeper the `StreamCorruptedException` we can see the exact point where this happens:

```
ValidationException.errorDecryptingPassword(ValidationException.java:901)
```

Googling I found a wird problem related to this, for which I'm still investigating the root cause. But the *why* is it happening, is because you are using a 32 char long password (exact length). Apparently is related to UUID lengths (32 char) and how JPA Provider is reading it. I'll update the answer when I find more, but change the password length and you should get rid of the `StreamCorruptedException`(I reproduced it in my local environment)

**Update** further investiogation

The error is already reported here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569945

To fail this way the password has to be 32 char long (or a multiple of 32) and consist of hexadecimal characters. This way eclipselink thinks it is and encrypted password and tries to decrypt it, throwing the exception you receive.

Comment: still doesn't work - and I do have a persistence.xml. I uploaded persistence.xml, the new code with what you told me to add and the new errors here: https://pastebin.com/K0wThZPA

Comment: Those fields that you've told me to initialize are initialized in initTransaction already though

Comment: Ok. Sorry, I don't know how I misses that `initTransaction`

Comment: Now I get other errors. I added them here, along with the modified pom.xml https://pastebin.com/Wu9Spht0

Comment: I updated the end of the answer.

Comment: I think I still get the same errors after updating the packages. Using JDK17. Here's the errors + new orm + new persistence

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PrF53spi

Comment: Updated the answer again. I think we nailed it this time :D I keep investigating... God, I love this xDDD

Comment: well I kept investigating too, tbh :) But the fact that I have no background in Java doesn't help much :). I've just read your updates - I'm using a Heroku cloud DB, and I can't change the password - it is 64 characters long. What should I do? Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: I changed my DB from a cloud one to a local one, so I can have a shorter password and it does work properly now. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Knowing that it is trying to decrypt it, you could try to encrypt your password :D But I don't exactly know how does that work.

Comment: Ok, if a local ddbb suits you too great then. You are most welcome :)

Now that we've closed it, if you don't mind I'm gonna reshape the answer. Knowing that the main problem was the password, people that reach this question will better get helped if I move the password conclusions at the beginning of the answer.